# 3-regular graphs with an odd number of vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Do there exist any 3-regular graphs with an odd number of vertices? I'm starting a delve into graph theory and can prove the existence of a 3-regular graph for any even number of vertices 4 or greater, but can't find any odd ones.

Answer (score 2):

The following is useful:

> **The Handshaking Lemma**:$$\sum_{v\in V} \deg(v) = 2|E|$$
>
> **Corrollary**: The number of vertices of odd degree in a graph must be even.
>
> **Corrollary 2**: No graph exists with an odd number of odd degree vertices.

Answer (score 0):

An odd number of odd vertices is impossible in any graph by the Handshake Lemma.